# How does url encoding/decoding work in web service calls

Tags: java, apache, web-services, api, urlencode

I need to consume a third party api which is expecting url as below
URL?queryParam=02/10/1990

when i am calling that api by appending queryParam(ab above) it is working fine.

But when I call api as below
GetMethod httpMethod = new GetMethod(url);
httpMethod.setQueryString(getNameValuePairs(requestParams));
where requestParams is map of request params.
api is giving 400 error.

api I am using here is apache.common apis

when I looked in setQueryString code,requestParams are url encoded.

so my doubts are.

1. Does queryParams are url encoded by default?it yes, Here apache api is encoding request param at consumer end,does consumer has to manually decode it?
2. When api is called from browser by appending queryParams does browser also do url encoding by itself?
3. What is the clean solution of it?

Comment: Use [UriBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html)

Comment: why will UriBuilder work?It also encodes query param.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to frame the uri and pass it to getMethod() constructor.

```
string url;
url = baseURL+"?queryParam=02/10/1990" ;

GetMethod httpMethod = new GetMethod(url);
```

Query params are mostly used for post Request payload.
In your case , there's on need fo

Comment: It gives illegal arg exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use base64 url encoding and decoding. It will solve the problem.